# JPA Hibernate left join fetch generating mutiple queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, fetch

I have a jpql query to eagerly fetch multi level associations as follows

```
  select distinct s from Singer s
  left join fetch s.singerIdentifiers si  //singerIdentifiers is collection in Singer object
  left join fetch si.identifier i
  left join fetch i.identifierReportedAreas ira
  left join fetch irc.reportedArea ra
  left join fetch rc.reportingSystem rs
  where s.id in (?);
```

This generates multiples queries, though I am getting all the required information in the first select itself. All extra queries are for querying SingerIdentifier table data for distinct IdentifierIds from the first query.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my "answer". I just tried, and similar query with as deep level of join fetches seems to work (Hibernate 3.5.6).

Comment: Hi Mikko Maunu,thanks for your effort. Did you try using associations with collections or just OneToOne associations? and How many queries it generated ? just want to know...

Comment: Hi, with @OneToMany Set<Ent[1-6]>, six levels: SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Ent1 e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.entities e2 LEFT JOIN FETCH e2. entities e3 LEFT JOIN ....

Comment: looks like issue mentioned here:https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4935                                                              I have bidirectional oneToOne association between identifier and singerIdentifier. I changed it to manyToOne & oneToMany, and it is generating just one query now.

Comment: Can you write the SQL query being generated on console for this HQL ?

Comment: How are you mapping all of the relations? Are they Sets? If this is not the case, does `Singer` has other collections as well? In such case are they Sets or List (bags)? Are they eager fetched? Does `singerIdentifiers` have other collections (eager fetched) as well?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a typo?

```
  left join fetch i.identifierReportedAreas -->ira<--
  left join fetch -->irc<---.reportedArea ra
```